# FontName from CTFontRef

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text, ctfont, ctfontref

I've a CTFontRef variable.

> `CTFontRef aFontRef;`

Getting Size of Font was easy :

```
CGFloat aFontSize = CTFontGetSize(aFontRef);
```

Please help me in retrieving the FontName.
I'm expecting the FontName to be something like **MarkerFelt-Wide**.

But, when I use methods like

```
CTFontCopyFullName(aFontRef)
```

I get **Marker Felt Wide**

Cheers
Roshit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want the PostScript name, which you can obtain through [`CTFontCopyPostScriptName()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontCopyPostScriptName).

The PostScript name is an internal name, and is generally the preferred way to refer to a font by name.

Comment: Ouch...!!!! How could I miss that one method on top.. MY BAD...         Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Y am i not able to accept this as my solution.. strange.. say i Need to wait for 5 mins.. :( worth the wait though... thanx a ton for the answer...